Where is vmlinux file for crash dump
I have setup kdump to help me diagnose a kernel crash (per redhat docs).  I've gotten as far as creating the dump file, and now want to examine the crash dump file.  The instructions say to execute (for example):
crash /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.18.0-5.el8.x86_64/vmlinux /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2018-10-06-14:05:33/vmcore

But I don't have a vmlinux file.  I looked int the directory matching my kernel ( /usr/lib/modules/5.14.0-427.37.1.el9_4.x86_64+debug) and it contains the content shown below.  But no vmlinux file! I have a vmlinuz but the crash program didn't like it.  Where do I find this vmlinux file, or do I have to create it?
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       51 Sep 24 17:25 build -> /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-427.37.1.el9_4.x86_64+debug
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   224287 Sep 24 17:25 config
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root      156 Oct  5 08:18 kernel
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   879087 Oct  5 08:19 modules.alias
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   834103 Oct  5 08:19 modules.alias.bin
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      461 Sep 24 17:25 modules.block
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     9236 Sep 24 17:25 modules.builtin
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root        0 Oct  5 08:19 modules.builtin.alias.bin
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    11585 Oct  5 08:19 modules.builtin.bin
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    75121 Sep 24 17:25 modules.builtin.modinfo
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   307245 Oct  5 08:19 modules.dep
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   400740 Oct  5 08:19 modules.dep.bin
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      387 Oct  5 08:19 modules.devname
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      155 Sep 24 17:25 modules.drm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       20 Sep 24 17:25 modules.modesetting
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1648 Sep 24 17:25 modules.networking
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    93145 Sep 24 17:25 modules.order
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      862 Oct  5 08:19 modules.softdep
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   499371 Oct  5 08:19 modules.symbols
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   591632 Oct  5 08:19 modules.symbols.bin
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root        5 Sep 24 17:25 source -> build
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   404401 Sep 24 17:25 symvers.gz
-rw-------.  1 root root  9446409 Sep 24 17:25 System.map
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root        6 Sep 24 17:24 systemtap
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root        6 Sep 24 17:25 updates
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root       40 Oct  5 08:18 vdso
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 27304248 Sep 24 17:25 vmlinuz
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root        6 Oct  5 08:19 weak-updates

